# pass variables to another script

Tags: gradle

New to gradle and read a few earlier posts on passing variables however none of them have a proper answer. Since gradle has come a long way now and my use case is simple, I hope I get an answer.

I have 2 gradle files -
build.gradle
docker.gradle

I use apply from: docker.gradle in the buildscript of build.gradle

build.gradle has a variable -
ext.appVersion = "1.0"

This variable has to be passed to docker.gradle. What is the best way to achieve this?

I tried extra properties ext.appVersion and that didnt work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may share the variables via project properties like so:

```
project.ext.appVersion = '123123'
```

But you have to note, the `project.ext.appVersion` variable should be declared before the `docker.gradle` is applied if you need it at the configuration phase. So, this will work

```
project.ext.appVersion = '123123'
apply from: 'docker.gradle'
```

But this won't

```
apply from: 'docker.gradle'
project.ext.appVersion = '123123'
```

Comment: It makes perfect sense. Gradle is evaluated in order.